# How can I show the content of a trigger with psql?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I know I can list the triggers with `\dft`. But how can I see one concrete trigger? I want to know details like on which events the trigger is executed, which function is executed and so on.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

OK, I found out about it myself.

The command `\dft` doesn't show the triggers itself (as I thought), it shows all trigger-functions (return-type trigger).

To see the trigger you can make `\dS <tablename>`, it shows not only columns of this table, but also all triggers defined on this table.

To show the source of the trigger-function (or any function) use `\df+ <functionname>`.

Comment: Use \ef <function_name> for more convenient reads.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't have access to psql commands, you can still use :

```
select pg_get_functiondef('functionname'::regproc);
```

Comment: Sometimes: `select pg_get_functiondef ('schema.functionname'::regproc);` (means, schema name prefix may be needed)

Answer (score 4):

You could try the following:

```
SELECT event_object_table,trigger_name,event_manipulation,action_statement,action_timing FROM information_schema.triggers ORDER BY event_object_table,event_manipulation
```

or you can show triggers of a table named 'testtable' like this:

```
SELECT event_object_table,trigger_name,event_manipulation,action_statement,action_timing FROM information_schema.triggers WHERE event_object_table='testtable' ORDER BY event_object_table,event_manipulation
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, you create `my_t` trigger which runs my_func() after UPDATE operation happens on `person` table for each row as shown below. *[My post](https://dev.to/hyperkai/a-trigger-in-postgresql-2p40) explains how to create a trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER my_t AFTER UPDATE ON person
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION my_func();
```

Now first, you need to get the OID(Object identifier) from [pg_trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-trigger.html) as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT oid FROM pg_trigger WHERE tgname = 'my_t';
  oid
-------
 16429
(1 row)
```

Then, you can get the code of `my_t` trigger with [pg_get_triggerdef()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html) and the OID as shown below. *[My post](https://dev.to/hyperkai/object-identifier-types-in-postgresql-52p7) explains an OID with a function:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT pg_get_triggerdef(16429);
                                     pg_get_triggerdef
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 CREATE TRIGGER my_t AFTER UPDATE ON public.person FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION my_func()
(1 row)
```

Or, you can get the OID from `pg_trigger` and get the code of `my_t` trigger with `pg_get_triggerdef()` and the OID at once as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT pg_get_triggerdef((SELECT oid FROM pg_trigger WHERE tgname = 'my_t'));
                                     pg_get_triggerdef
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 CREATE TRIGGER my_t AFTER UPDATE ON public.person FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION my_func()
(1 row)
```